# Hunchback named Bartholomew discovers a spaceship full of booby traps

Tags: story-identification, space

I'm trying to remember a name of a book that took place on a spacecraft, with a hunchback character named Bartholomew. they notice a ship following them and eventually go investigate, the ship turns out to be full of booby traps. That's about all I can remember. thanks for any help.

Comment: Maybe this is a stretch, but can you remember when you first read it? About how old you think it was?

Answer (score 4):

I believe you're looking for [Ship Of Fools](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ship_of_Fools_%28Russo_novel%29) by Richard Russo (published as Unto Leviathan in the UK)

The main character is a hunchback, called Bartolomeo Aguilera; it's set on a generation ship looking for a new world to settle, and among other plot lines, the ship detects and begins to explore a mysterious ship, that's either crammed full of deadly traps, or just designed by aliens in a way that makes sense to them, but happens to look like a ship full of deadly traps to human sensibilities.

Comment: That's it. Thank you so much. spent a long time on Google trying to figure that out.

Comment: You can click the checkmark under the voting buttons to accept.